# If $A \lhd P$ and $A = C_P(A)$, then $|P:A|$ divides $(|A| - 1)!$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

This is problem 1.D.10 in Isaacs, [Finite Group Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821843443).

> Let $A$ be maximal among the abelian normal subgroups of a $p$-group $P$. Show that $A = C_P(A)$, and deduce that $|P:A|$ divides $(|A|-1)!$

I proved the first part, $A = C_P(A)$, and I *think* I got the second part, $|P:A|$ divides $(|A|-1)!$, but I'm self-studying, so **I would like to check my logic for the second part**.

**My proof:**

The number $|A|-1$ struck me as a bit odd. The only natural set of that size that came to mind is the set of nonidentity elements of $A$. Let us call this set $X$.

Now $P$ acts on $X$ by conjugation, since $A \lhd P$ and since $pxp^{-1} = 1$ if and only if $x = 1$.

A point $x \in X$ is fixed by $p \in P$ if and only if $p \in C_P(x)$. The kernel of the action is the set of elements $p \in P$ which fix every $x \in X$. This occurs if and only if
$$p \in \bigcap_{x \in X}C_P(x) = \bigcap_{x \in A}C_P(x) = C_P(A) = A$$
The first equality holds because $A = X \cup \{1\}$, and $C_P(1) = P$. The last equality was proved in the first part of the problem. We have thus shown that the kernel of the action is $A$.

Consequently, the action induces an isomorphism between $P/A$ and a subgroup of $S_X$. This means that $|P:A|$ divides $|S_X| = (|X|)! = (|A|-1)!$, as desired.

---

Of course, we could have simply let $P$ act on $A$ and avoided the funny business of excluding the identity, but that would only allow us to conclude that $|P:A|$ divides $(|A|)!$, and every little bit helps when dealing with factorials...

Comment: This works perfectly well. The only thing I would change is when you want to prove that $P$ acts on $X$ by conjugation. IMHO you could say $P$ acts on $A$ by conjugation, since $\{1\}$ is one orbit of this action (because $p1p^{-1}=1$ for any $p\in P$) $P$ also acts on $X:=A-\{1\}$.

Comment: @ClémentGuérin: Thanks, that makes sense. It seems that this general principle holds: if a group $G$ acts on a set $X$ containing multiple orbits, then $G$ also acts on $X \setminus O$ where $O$ is any of the orbits.

Comment: This general principle holds indeed, it just comes from the fact that if $G$ acts on $X$ and $Y\subseteq X$, $G$ acts on $Y$ (by the induced action) if and only if $Y$ is a union of orbits of the action of $G$ over $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks good! In general, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $N_G(H)/C_G(H)$ embeds homomorphically in Aut$(H)$. And Aut$(H)$ acts faithfully on the set of non-identity elements of $H$, and so $|\text {Aut}(H)|$ divides $(|H|-1)!$. See also Lemma(9.14) in your book!

Comment: Nice, something to look forward to! At this pace, I should get to chapter 9 sometime in the next few years. :-) I know the $N/C$ theorem (it's in the appendix "The Basics") but I seldom notice opportunities to use it.

Comment: Well, you do not have to study the book linearly. Some of the chapters can be read independently of each other! Good luck!

Comment: Ha, I must be obtuse, I just noticed that if $|P:A|$ divides $(|A|-1)!$, then $|P|$ divides $|A|!$, which certainly comes in handy in the next problem, which is: If $n$ is the maximum order among abelian subgroups of a finite group $G$, then $|G|$ divides $n!$. That's a nice theorem, I don't think I have encountered it before.